clicking the title bar in 24.04 evokes buggy window tiling behaviour
I just updated from 23.10 to 24.04 and I noticed a very annoying thing: whenever I (SINGLE!) click the gnome top title bar (with the clock), it goes through some kind of window tiling routine: it resizes my current window and shows two or three red suggestion boxes in rapid succession, as if I were tiling my windows (you know, by dragging them to a screen edge or using SUPER+arrow).
The buggy nature makes me believe it's not on purpose. How can I stop this?

Ubuntu 24.04 (noble) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the development release Ubuntu noble and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu noble you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc.  This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues, and please note the release is still in beta   You'll be on-topic here (if you wish to wait) after release of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.

my bad I thought it was already official as it came through with my do-release-upgrade but I had added -d so I'm on a develop release.

It is now official and the bug persists. You can disable the behavior in settings -> Ubuntu Desktop -> Enhanced Tiling

yep. I like the tiling though so I'll wait for the bugfix.

This is indeed a bug. The upstream developer of the Tiling-Assistant extension already fixed this in their version 47 of the extension, but it did not yet make it to Ubuntu's version of the extension.
See this answer for more details: How to disable Ubuntu 24.04's toggle maximize on titlebar single click?

looks like a functional version was released today

Same here. Try to turn off the Tiling Assistant by Leaflet in your Gnome Extensions. :)

Thanks @Andrei Ambrazevich, I disabled the extension for now.

OMG finally.
Win + up no longer works to maximise windows, but honestly I'm happy to sacrifice it at this point.
